# How to use svg icon set package from node_modules in angular4?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, svg

I have found this open source icon package which I installed in my project [featherIcons](https://github.com/colebemis/feather), and is listed inside my_modules directory. However Im trying to use it but I just cant seem to make it work.

The issue is, I think I have to be somehow importing the package but not sure how or where.

**`app-component.html`**

```html
<div class="navbar__nav-container">
  <ul class="navbar__nav-container__nav-items">
    <li>Platform</li>
    <li>Stix/Taxi</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>
      <i data-feather="circle"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**`app.module.ts`**

```js
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { RoutingModule } from './routing.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { CatService } from './services/cat.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuardLogin } from './services/auth-guard-login.service';
import { AuthGuardAdmin } from './services/auth-guard-admin.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CatsComponent } from './cats/cats.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CatsComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuardLogin,
    AuthGuardAdmin,
    CatService,
    UserService
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured the solution, and I'll post the solution here so that it can help the rest.

So as the library states in the link provided, I had to install it like so

**`npm install feather-icons --save`** - the **`--save`** is very important because it will be referenced in my `package.json`. Once installed, you will be able to see it in `node_modules` directory.

Then in which ever component I want to use the library, all I had to do is import it the following way:

Since I wanted to use an icon from the library in `app.component.ts`:

**`app.component.ts`**

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';

/*
- feather-icons is a directory installed in node_modules.
- I dont have to specify the whole path like '../node_modules/path/to/feather-icons'.
- Also rememeber to call the feather.replace() inside ngOnInit
- because it needs to first make sure the component loads first
*/
import * as feather from 'feather-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor (
    public auth: AuthService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    feather.replace();
  }

}
```

Then in my `app.component.html`:

```html
<div class="navbar__nav-container">
  <ul class="navbar__nav-container__nav-items">
    <li>Platform</li>
    <li>Stix/Taxi</li>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>
      <i data-feather="circle"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This was all to it to be honest.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but when i put *ngIf in <li> icon not show, any idea?

Comment: Can you explain what is done here newcomers to Angular?

Comment: Suppose, you are using the icons across the project, then how many times you will call the feather.replace() in the whole project?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution using [angular-feather](https://github.com/michaelbazos/angular-feather)

The advantage of it being that you cherry pick only the icons that you need, thus reducing bundle size.

1. Install the package

   ```
   npm install angular-feather
   ```
2. Import the icons you need

   Import the icons a la carte in the angular module of your needs

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

   import { FeatherModule } from 'angular-feather';
   import { Camera, Heart, Github } from 'angular-feather/icons';

   // Select some icons (use an object, not an array)
   const icons = {
     Camera,
     Heart,
     Github
   };

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       FeatherModule.pick(icons)
     ],
     exports: [
       FeatherModule
     ]
   })
   export class IconsModule {}
   ```
3. Import IconsModule and use component

   ```
   <i-feather name="heart"></i-feather>
   <i-feather name="camera"></i-feather>
   ```

#### [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-feather)

Comment: it doesnt work because it says the the appmodule has undefined value. and IconAlertTriangle is not a module

Comment: Plus your refering to another package. I'm not refering to angular-feather. I'm refering to another package. See the link plz

Comment: Angular feather is the angular implementation of feather icon

Comment: This should be the accepted as best answer, it's provide the right angular way of using third party dependencies